# Function makes an array empty

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertion_sort(char[], int);
void swap(char*, char*);

int main() {
    char s[] = "hello world";
    puts(s);
    insertion_sort(s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(char));
    puts("done\n");
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}

void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp; 
}

void insertion_sort(char s[], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    /* counters */
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        j=i;
        while ((j>0) && (s[j] < s[j-1])) {
            swap(&s[j],&s[j-1]);
            j = j-1;
        }
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

The problem is, after the `insertion_sort()` function call, `s` becomes empty - `puts(s)` prints nothing.

Please advise.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in your debugger - you will not only find and fix your bug, but you will learn a lot in the process

Comment: The NUL terminator of the string is put in front. That's the reason.

Comment: @Paul I wrote this app in Vim, not an IDE with debugger. I hoped it'll work w/o debugging. But thanks for your advise, I'll try to open my app in an IDE and debug it.

Comment: You don't need an IDE for debugging - you can just use gdb directly.

Comment: Use a command line debugger then.

Comment: Or use `printf()` debugging.  Though I'd suggest trying `gdb` first.

Comment: I tried debugging and found that null terminating character '\0' was placed to the beginning of the string. And that caused `puts` to not print anything. Although I couldn't see what's going on inside `puts`, because it's defined in c library, Information I got was quite sufficient to understand the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
insertion_sort(s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(char));
```

to:

```
insertion_sort(s, strlen(s));
```

otherwise you will be including the `'\0'` terminator of `s[]` in your sort.

Note that you will need an additional header for `strlen` so change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

to:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf etc
#include <string.h>   // strlen etc
```

Comment: strlen is located in string.h so don't forget to #include<string.h>

Comment: @Zekian: thanks - good point - I have now updated the answer to cover this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the length that you pass to `insertion_sort` includes terminating `\0` character, which happens to have value `0`, so in sort it is placed as the first element of your array. This is why your last `puts()` prints nothing - because the first character is now "the end of a string".

I suggest you to calculate the size of a string using `strlen()` which will return the length of a string excluding terminating character. Or if you want to do it your way, take terminating character into consideration and substract it from the total length.